When you don't score enough points on a test in an engineering school, do you "fail a course" or "fail a class"?
I've noticed some people, when referring to the act of taking a test at an engineering school and not scoring enough points at that test, say "fail a class". How does that phrase make sense? Subjects of study at engineering schools (and elsewhere in higher education) are called "courses" and not "classes", right? So, why don't they say "fail a course"?
For example, this guy says, at the very beginning of the video: "What, 50 years, 40-something years you have of living your life, and you were just about to switch out from engineering because you failed one or two classes, are you kidding me?". Why doesn't he say "courses" instead of "classes"?

Did you consult a dictionary to see if there's a definition of "class" that overlaps with the definition of "course"? For example, see Merriam-Webster online, definition 1c: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class

These things vary a lot between countries. But it will also depend on the details of the program of study. So what do you mean by "course" or "class"? How long is this? How many do you do in a year, semester, term, or over the full degree program? (Although at least in the UK, everything seems to be a "module" these days.)

If the test is a final exam that counts as a large percentage of the grade for the entire course (this varies a lot from  professor to professor) failing the final exam can result in failing the course.

There really is no reason to dv this question.

To take a course or a class
To fail a course or a class
Merriam Webster has this for class:
4
as in course

a series of lectures on a subject
took a class on modern art

So, in that sense, fail a course or class are both acceptable.
And both are acceptable in BrE or AmE.
In BrE, they tend to say failed a course or module or exam or year.

Quite a few Americans more recently refer to having failed the class, but it's still very much a minority usage. And imho the much lower levels in the British corpus might be significantly affected by misclassifications. In BrE a class is usually a lesson, not a course.

@FumbleFingers ngrams is irrelevent. We say both in AmE. Fail a class is used all the time in American English. spoken American English. Also, class as a lesson (My maths lesson is at 11 am) is not the meaning here. It's true that in the UK failed a course is perhaps more usual, yes.

Just from personal experience of living in the midwest US my entire life, "fail a class" is much more common here, no matter what the Ngrams say. Obviously "course" is still said occasionally and would be understood though.

@YonKuma If you take a course or class, you can pass it or fail it. And the midwest thing is really irrelevant.

"Failed the class" might edge out "failed the course" in a high school setting, and vice versa in a college setting.

@Lambie: "perhaps"? I would say that fail a class is extremely unlikely in BrE.

@ColinFine I said both were acceptable but not that British English uses it. I specifically said above: fail a course or module for BrE and I'll add now exam or year.

@TimR Ask a Professor: What to Do if You’re Failing a Class in College https://www.bestcolleges.com/blog/what-to-do-failing-class/|| 370 google hits, if that means anything. There are fewer hits for fail a course than fail a class with a general google search of: college + fail a class and college + fail a course

@lambie I don't use the internet as an arbiter.

@TimR Perhaps not, but it's pretty clear reading the first page of hits from colleges etc, that you are mistaken. College courses are often referred to as classes and failing a class is used in that context all the time by just about everyone. That said, fail a course is more formal, fail a class is less so, in AmE.

@Lambie I don't think there's any formal/informal difference either.

@TimR Of course there would be. An official communication/text from/by a college/university is more likely to say fail a course rather than fail a class.  For example: If a student fails a course, the course is not credited toward the degree, but the failing grade remains on the student’s transcript and a 0.0 is calculated into the student’s cumulative average.  Boston College

@Lambie The communication from the college would use the word "course" because that's what they're usually called at the college level, as I commented above.   course isn't  a formal term. One drunken frat bro could say to another, "Dude, how many courses are you taking this semester?"

@TimR Yes, but an official communication from the university would say fail a course, not fail a class. Now I have said that twice. And that's right. Regardless of frat boys. fail a course is more university or college administrative language, ergo, more formal and more precise, in fact.

@FumbleFingers fail a class is very common in American English.

So you said before. But I don't know why you think "ngrams is irrelevent". As my NGram clearly shows, even allowing for the rapid rise of failed the class over the past couple of decades, it's not so common as failed the course. And that's in the AmE corpus - it's far less common in the BrE corpus, which is specifically what motivated my first comment.

@FumbleFingers  It's irrelevant because failed the class would not be as prevalent in the contexts you get through ngrams that are written contexts. Therefore,  you have no basis for saying that re American English and I can guarantee you I have heard it my entire life as a speaker of AmE. So,  you should remove that comment.  It's false.  [[but it's still very much a minority usage]] Wrong, I cannot stress that enough.
